# Gauge dependence of Feynman propagator

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, gauge

In QED we have the property that any gauge dependence must cancel out in physical quantities. Nevertheless Feynman rules display some gauge dependence. This is what I am a little unclear on.

The obvious place gauge dependence comes into Feynman rules is through the propagator
$$\frac{-i}{k^2 - m^2} \bigg( \eta^{\mu \nu} - (1-\xi)\frac{k^{\mu}k^{\nu}}{k^2} \bigg) $$
I take it that if I calculated some physical quantity using this general form of the propagator there would be no $\xi$ dependence at the end of the day. However we also have freedom in the polarisation vectors. Under a gauge transformation $$\epsilon^\mu_r \longrightarrow \epsilon^\mu_r + i k^\mu c_r(k)$$ the amplitude should be invariant. For external photons $\mathcal{M} = \epsilon^\mu_r \mathcal{M}^\mu $ then this works nicely via the Ward identity $k_\mu \mathcal{M}^\mu = 0$.

On the other hand deriving the photon propagator in a slightly more physical way (rather than via gauge fixing) we find that the numerator of the propagator actually arises from the polarisation sum
$$ \sum_r \epsilon^\mu_r \epsilon^{\nu *}_r $$
I therefore expect the polarisation sum to change as you change the gauge. Does this work out the way I expect? Do we have that:

1. **In the Feynman gauge ($\xi = 1)$ the polarisation sum is $\sum_r \epsilon^\mu_r \epsilon^{\nu *}_r = -\eta^{\mu \nu}$.**
2. **If I then do $\epsilon^\mu_r \longrightarrow \epsilon^\mu_r + i k^\mu c_r(k)$ then the polarisation sum is $\sum_r ( \epsilon^\mu_r + i k^\mu c_r(k)) ( \epsilon^{\nu}_r + i k^\nu c_r(k))^* $ which allows me to relate the new $\xi$ and the gauge transformation function $c_r(k)$? Exactly how does this work? Aren't I going to get cross terms $ ~ k^\mu \epsilon^{\nu}_r $?**

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I see you've asked a couple of questions in this vein. I think what you may be looking for is the Fadeev-Poppov method which makes clear how and why all results will be independent of the gauge we choose despite working with objects that are not manifestly gauge invariant.